# Create a service in linux using shell script

Tags: scripts, services

I want to create a service in linux as we do in windows. which i can start or stop with help of a script. the service has to launch a gaming application which has some dependencies associated with it.

Basically i want a script executing which creates a service in linux, this service will basically launch a gaming application(launching is also done through a script) , so its like the service has to launch a script.

**Purpose of the service**: i will like the service to auto restart the application in case it crashes. *Got to know that auto restart of application can be done through services*

please help me on this i am new to linux :(

Comment: some more information would help

Comment: updated question....

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling that you only mention "service" because on Windows it's possible to configure a service to auto-restart when it crashes. I even think it wouldn't be easy to make an arbitrary "game application" to work as a service on Windows because services run with limited privileges.

If you need a script which auto-restarts an application if the latter exits with a non-zero error code (i.e. when it crashes), check [Anycorn's answer to a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703227/self-restart-program-on-segfault-under-linux). It's very simple and it does not involve any services.

If you want step-by-step instructions, here what I would do:

create a directory called bin in your home folder:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

create a script "startgame" in that directory:

```
touch ~/bin/startgame
```

open it in a text editor:

```
gedit ~/bin/startgame
```

enter the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do /path/to/game/executable && break; done
```

save the file;

set executable bit on it:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/startgame
```

execute the script by typing in the terminal

```
startgame
```

All of the above can be achieved without terminal - i.e. create a folder using Nautilus, create a file, make it executable; create a desktop shortcut etc.

If you're interested how the script works:

```
while [ 1 ]; do ... done
```

is an infinite loop

```
/path/to/game/executable
```

starts the application and waits for it to finish (obvously, you need to change it to the actual path of your application)

```
command1 && command2
```

executes command1 and then executes command2 *only if* command1 terminated with a zero return code (which indicates success). I.e. the loop will only stop ('break' statement) if the program terminated without an error, otherwise it'll be restarted.

Comment: ya you got me right its basically for auto restart stuff... but i am unable to understand the solution been provide at this link...

Comment: @Varun: I updated the answer

Comment: If you replace  `while [ 1 ];` with something like `while [ ! -e /var/run/stop_the_loop ];` you can break the loop by creating the file `/var/run/stop_the_loop`. That can be useful sometimes.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch the original "recipe", which usage I tried to explain, mentioned a 2-second sleep before restarting the program - in this case a second Ctrl-C would allow to break the loop, which probably is even easier then creating a file in /var/run/

Comment: @Sergey - wat if i want to stop the application... i had another script for stopping it... will share the both script in sometime.. feels like a big noob :(

Comment: @Varun: exiting the application normally (i.e. using its Close/Quit/Exit option) should return exit status 0 which should break the loop and terminate the script. Note that we're talking about a "gaming application" - i.e. a "normal" application which has some UI, opens some windows or somehow else interacts with the user and is running in the context of the user's session. If you need to auto-restart something which is a daemon - i.e. a system process without UI, which starts at system boot time without user loggin in, such as a webserver - the ways to set it up are completely different.